# swap bits in different positions in 2 char_type variables

Tags: c, byte, swap

I would like to swap a segment of bits between 2 unsigned char_type variables:a and b. How to address it in C language if the segment is not sequential? For example, a is **011**001**10**, input segment length:5, start position pa=5, the segment is from bit7~bit5 and bit1~bit0, which is **011 10**; b is **10**011**001**, position pb=6, the segment is from bit6~bit7 and bit2~bit0, which is **10 001**. The 2 segments have the same length. The expect result result should be like that: a1= 11000100, b1= 11011001

I tried to use 2 temp variables x and y to store swap bits in b and a, and then use ^ to finish swap. The method is too complex. Is there any tricky idea?

Comment: `I tried to use 2 temp variables ` ... why don't you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Just to double check, you're saying you have `a=011(001)10` and `b=10(011)001` and you want to swap a subset of the bits such that `a=011(011)10` and `b=10(001)001`?

Comment: I used three temp variables, and the method was not complex.

Comment: @Mike My expect result is : a1=110(001)10 and b1=11(011)100. Bits in () should be kept and out of () should be swapped. Clearer for understanding?

Comment: @LihO I have changed the content for question and my idea is described there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoiler: (I use bigger types than char)

```
void swapmask(unsigned *a, unsigned *b, unsigned posa, unsigned posb, unsigned len)
{
unsigned mask, fraga, fragb;

#include <limits.h>
if (len >= CHAR_BIT* sizeof *a) return ;
if (posa >= CHAR_BIT* sizeof *a) return ;
if (posb >= CHAR_BIT* sizeof *b) return ;

mask = (1u << len) -1;
fraga = (*a >> posa) & mask;
fragb = (*b >> posb) & mask;

fprintf(stderr, "Mask=%x Fa=%x, Fb=%x\n", mask, fraga, fragb);

*a = (*a & ~(mask << posa)) | (fragb << posa);
*b = (*b & ~(mask << posb)) | (fraga << posb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution finally addresses my issue.

Comment: I still do not understand what unsigned *a stand for, hence a is a char_type variable. By the way, what is the meaning of "(*a >> posa)"?

Comment: As I said: I changed the types to unsigned (int). You could easily change the `unsigned` to `unsigned char`. The `*a` means "pointer dereference" (take the value that a points to). Sigh.